# Automatically number paragraphs

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr, bookdown

The report format I am working with requires each paragraph to be numbered. Is there a way to implement automatic paragraph numbering in R markdown? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to solve your question is to create a counter manually and inlcude this before every paragraph and make it print with the brakets like this:

````
---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
x <- 0
```

# title 1
`r (x <- x+1)` bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1 bla1

`r (x <- x+1)` bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2 bla2

# title 2
`r (x <- x+1)` bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3 bla3
````

The result will be this:
[image]

Comment: interesting and thanks! Seems implementable as a feature that can be controlled in YAML.

Comment: I also need to work out the indentation that is usually associated with numbered paragraphs. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user39008 you can add one or multiple sequences of "&nbsp;" at the linestart (without the two " though) - this will create one or more blanks

Comment: adding "indent: true" in YAML did the trick, thanks!